# How to combine "social", "cultural" and "miIeu"

Tags: word-order

Would it be

> socio-cultural-milieu

or

> sociocultural-milieu

or

> socio-cultural milieu

or

> sociocultural milieu

Comment: I like option 3.

Comment: Sociocultural milieu or socio-cultural milieu: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sociocultural+milieu%2Csocio+cultural+milieu%2Csocio-cultural+milieu%2C+socio-cultural-milieu&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csociocultural%20milieu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csocio%20cultural%20milieu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csocio%20-%20cultural%20milieu%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Did you lose that V in a magic accident?

Comment: @TRomano I imagine it got lost along with the L missing from the title.

Answer (score 1):

It would be sociocultural milieu. Sociocultural does not require a hyphen, and milieu is a noun. If milieu were an adjective, then it would be prudent to use the hyphen between socicultural and milieu. Hope this helps.

Reference:

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/milieu?s=t

-Tim

Comment: Please try and provide from supporting information or cite references to strengthen your point. Else it would count as an opinion. Good Luck.